# VisualStateManager.GoToState not hiding control

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am trying to hide a grid's visibility using the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method. If I call the method while the app started up normally, the control is hidden as expected. The problem occurs when I `Suspend and shutdown(terminate)` then resume the app. In the `OnNavigationLoadState` I make a call to the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` which should hide the grid's visibility however the control is still visible after the call.

Here is the grid I am trying to hide:

```
        <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            Width="350"
            Visibility="{Binding Path = ShowGrid, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
            <customControls:MyCustomControl x:Name="EntityListViewControl" />
```

Here is the visual state that is responsible for hiding this control:

```
            <VisualState x:Name="HideControl">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="Collapsed" KeyTime="0"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
```

Here is the call from the code behind during the resuming of the app:

```
protected override void OnNavigationLoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "HideControl", true);
}
```

If I set the dependency property of the grid (`ShowGrid`) in the `OnNavigationLoadState` to `false` the grid is hidden however I still want to know why the `VisualStateManager` does not work. Again, the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` behaves as expected if I make a call to it once the app is running, it just does not working during the resuming event. I also checked the boolean return value of the call inside the `OnNavigationLoadState` and it returns true.

Comment: I think it's recommended to put all `GoToState()` calls in a single method like `UpdateVisualStates(bool useTransitions)`. The one reason I think you might have a problem is another call to `GoToState()` elsewhere might be switching the state to make your control visible. This tends to happen less if all of the `GoToState()` calls are together. It's very likely the problem is elsewhere of course, but it might require some debugging to see and you'd need to share more of your code to enable a repro.

Comment: BTW, IIRC when your app suspends and then gets terminated - it basically restarts, so it shouldn't behave differently unless you're doing something different for the two startup paths in app.xaml.cs.

Comment: After further debugging, I found that two calls were being made to the VisualStateManager.GoToState method. If I skipped the first call and executed the second, the Visual State updates correctly. Is this normal behavior when two calls are made do to go to the same Visual State?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem normal. Are you sure they were going to the same visual state? Maybe one of them wasn't running on a UI thread?